# the type org.springframework.core.nestedruntimeexception cannot be resolved.It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: spring

While  using ApplicationContext in my main class.I am getting the below error

`the type org.springframework.core.NestedRuntimeException cannot be resolved.It is indirectly referenced from required .class files`

I am using Spring 4.3.7 with maven.Please help

[image]

Comment: I am not facing this issue with 4.3.6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem and it happened because my local repository was corrupted. I manually deleted the local repository and forced maven to download again

Answer (score 1):

Just go to your .m2 folder where your dependency(springframework) is downloaded and manually delete it.
Then again paste the dependency in your pom.xml file and save it.But do it with a stable internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

I would just using spring boot ...it makes starting with spring easier. That error is occurring because you don't have all the correct jars in yoour class path e.g. add to your maven/gradle/buildpath file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Cann't use ApplicationContext.If I use only Spring-core

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use the same Spring framework dependencies version for all spring-jar.

[image]

Comment: please do not post pictures of code but rather the code itself

Answer (score 0):

i have updated old dependency with new one and it working fine

Comment: Noman, welcome to community. Suggestion - Please keep adding your valuable comments under comment section of question instead of adding ansers. This is what everyone is following here. Thanks